Alternative characterization of pretopological convergence?
Let $(E,\to)$ be a convergence space, i.e., a set $E$ endowed with a relation $\to$ on ${\rm Filters}(E)\times E$, satisfying to two following axioms :

For every $x\in E$, the principal filter $\{\{x\}\}^{\uparrow E}$ converges to $x$ :  $\{\{x\}\}^{\uparrow E}\to x$.
If $\cal F\to x$ and $\cal G\geq F$ (for the usual inclusion preorder on filters) then $\cal G\to x$.

It is well known that $(E,\to)$ defines a pretopological space if, and only if, its convergence relation $\to$ satisfies the following, additional property :

For every family $\{\cal F_j\}$ of filters such that $\forall j,\cal F_j\to x$, their intersection filter still converges to $x$: $\bigcap_j \cal F_j \to x$.

(Indeed, when property 3 holds, the neighborhood filter of the pretopology at each point $x$ can be defined as the intersection of all filters converging to $x$, i.e. : $\cal N(x):=\bigcap_{\cal F\to x}\cal F$. See for example this ncatlab page.)
Once that a convergence space is known to be a pretopological space, it is relatively easy to prove that its convergence relation $\to$ verifies the following, additional property:

If a filter $\cal F$ is such that every subfilter of $\cal F$ has a subfilter that converges to $x$, then $\cal F$ converges to $x$ :
$\quad(\forall \cal G\geq F, \; \exists \cal H\geq\cal G,\; \cal H \to x) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \cal F\to x$

And so my question: is property 4 equivalent to property 3, or is it strictly weaker ? If a convergence space $(E,\to)$ satisfies property 4, is it necessarily a pretopological space ?
Some context : this Wikipedia page uses property 4 (restated in terms of nets) as one of the axioms that a convergence relation on nets should verify to define a topology. Their two first axioms are points 1 and 2 from my above list, i.e., they state that we are in a convergence space. Their third axiom is property 4 from my list. So I was wondering whether these three first axioms suffice to make the convergence space into a pretopological space. (Assuming that their fourth and final axiom makes that pretopological space into a topological space.)
EDIT, 12/14/2024: What I called `property 4' actually characterizes a subcategory of convergence spaces called pseudotopological spaces which is, indeed, more general than pretopological spaces. See here.

EDIT: As of August 24th, 2024, I think I have largely answered my own question. To recall the question, a convergence space $(E,\to)$ can potentially verify the two following, additional properties (using the same numbering as in my original question):

For every family of filters $({\cal F}_j)$ such that $\forall j,{\cal F}_j\to x$, one has $\bigcap_j {\cal F}_j \to x$.

For every filter $\cal F$, if $\cal F$ is such that every subfilter $\cal G\geq\cal F$ admits a subfilter $\cal H\geq\cal G$ such that ${\cal H}\to x$, then one has ${\cal F}\to x$.


A convergence space where property 3 holds is a pretopological space, and then property 4 also holds. My question was about the reverse implication : if property 4 holds, what can we say about property 3?
In the response below, I show two things :
A. Property 4 implies a 'degraded' version of property 3, where the intersection is limited to finite families of filters.
B. One can build a convergence space where property 4 holds, but not property 3. (This is the part added in my edited answer.)
So the basic answer to my question is no, property 4 is not equivalent to property 3, it is strictly weaker. In general, it does not suffice to characterize convergence spaces that are pretopological.

A. Property 4 implies a degraded version of property 3.
Let us prove the following:
Proposition: Let $(E,\to)$ be a convergence space where the following additional property holds : if ${\cal F}$ is a filter on $E$ such that
$\forall {\cal G\geq F},\; \exists {\cal H}\geq {\cal G},\; {\cal H}\to x $,
then $\cal F\to x$.
Let a finite family of filters $({\cal F}_i)_{i=1\dots n}$ such that $\forall i$, ${\cal F}_i\to x$. Then, one has
$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n {\cal F}_i \to x$.
Proof:
Note ${\cal F}:=\bigcap_{i=1}^n{\cal F}_i$, and consider some filter $\cal G$ such that $\cal G\geq \cal F$. For every $i= 1\dots n$, introduce the subset of ${\cal P}(E)$:
$$ {\cal H}_i :=\{A\cap D\,|\, A\in{\cal G}, D\in{\cal F}_i\}$$
Suppose that for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $\emptyset\in{\cal H}_i$. That is, we can find $A_i\in\cal G$, $D_i\in{\cal F}_i$ such that $A_i\cap D_i=\emptyset$. But then, setting $A:=\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$ and $D:=\bigcup_{i=1}^n D_i$, we would have $A\in\cal G$, $D\in\cal F\subset G$, and $A\cap D=\emptyset$, which is impossible.
Thus, there is at least one $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $\emptyset\notin {\cal H}_i$. It is then mechanical to prove that this ensemble ${\cal H}_i$ is a filter. Furthermore, by construction, it verifies ${\cal H}_i\geq {\cal G}$, and ${\cal H}_i\geq {\cal F}_i$ which implies ${\cal H}_i\to x$ (by the property of convergence spaces).
In conclusion, for every $\cal G\geq\cal F$, we can find some ${\cal H}\geq\cal G$ such that $\cal H\to x$. We deduce that $\cal F=\bigcap_{i=1}^n{\cal F}_i\to x$, QED.
Note: In the above proof, we needed a finite family of filters to ensure that $A:=\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$ is still in $\cal G$. This is the part that fails when considering an infinite family.

B. A convergence space where property 4 holds, but not property 3.
Given a set $E$ of infinite cardinality, let us note $\cal I$ the ensemble of all finite subsets of $E$.
Now consider the following convergence relation for filters on $E$:
$$\cal F \to x \quad:\Longleftrightarrow\quad \cal F\cap \cal I\neq\emptyset$$
This is a very coarse convergence: if $\cal F$ contains a finite set, it converges... to every $x\in E$ ! Else, it does not converge. We can easily verify that the space $(E,\to)$ so defined satisfies the two axioms of a convergence space (points 1 and 2 from the original question).
In the convergence space so defined:

The intersection of a finite number of converging filters ${\cal F}_i$ is clearly converging: since it contains a finite union of finite sets, which is still a finite set.

On the other hand, the intersection of an arbitrary number of converging filters may fail to be converging. So property 3 does not hold (this convergence space is not pretopological).


Let us now prove that this convergence space verifies property 4. Consider a filter $\cal F$ that is not converging (i.e., it contains no finite subset). Let
$$ {\cal G}:=\{A - S \,|\, A\in{\cal F}, S\in {\cal I}\}$$
In words: a set is in $\cal G$ iif. it is obtained by removing a finite number of points from a set in $\cal F$.
Obviously, $\cal G$ cannot contain a finite set, since every $A\in\cal F$ is infinite. It is easy to deduce that $\cal G$ is still a filter. By construction, it verifies $\cal G\geq\cal F$.
Now consider some filter $\cal H\geq G$. Assume $\cal H$ contains a finite set $S\in\cal I$. Then, its complement $S^\complement=E-S$ would be in $\cal G$, and thus also in $\cal H$, which is impossible. So $\cal H$ cannot contain a finite set, i.e., it cannot be converging.
We have shown that
$$\cal F\nrightarrow x\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \exists\cal G\geq F,\;\forall\cal H\geq G,\;\cal H\nrightarrow x$$
which is exactly property 4 (expressed in its contraposed form).
This counter-example proves that, in general, property 4 does not imply property 3.
